# Weird grey border around an image inside a swiper slide

Tags: javascript, css, swiper.js

I'm using vue swiper - https://swiperjs.com/vue, and I basically have a vertical swiper with a `Lazy` module so that the images inside my slides are loaded in a lazy way. My code is very simple:

```
<Swiper>
  <SwiperSlide>
   <div class="flex items-center gap-5">
    <div class="overflow-hidden rounded-full w-14 h-14">
       <img
        :data-src="/image.png"
        :data-srcset="/image.png 2x"
        class="object-cover w-full h-full swiper-lazy"
       >
    </div>
    <div class="flex flex-col col-span-3">
      <p class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900"> Title </p>
      <p class="text-xs text-gray-600"> Subtitle </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </SwiperSlide>
</Swiper>
```

The thing that I noticed is that every time my swiper slides (either automatically or manually) the images are getting some weird grey "border" in the beginning, which eventually is replaced with an image. However, if I delete the `src` and `srcset` params the "border" is still there, whether the image is rounded or not. The slide looks like this:

[image]

I checked all the posible css configs and there is literally nothing - no border, outline, box-shadow, or anything like that. Has anyone encountered such an issue before, how is it possible to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a white background I would add to the parent or the img element white background. I see that you use tailwindcss then add `bg-white`.

### update

if you remove the class w-full from
`class="object-cover w-full h-full swiper-lazy "` 
then you won't get the gray border if you don't have an image.

Comment: Even if I add some background, these corners are still visible...it seems like they are inside these images

Comment: @MikeL. Are you tried with a other image (like jpg) ?

Comment: The thing here is that it appears when there is no image...when there is I don't see these corners any longer

Comment: @MikeL. Ok. One idea where to create a placeholder image then you can avoid that.

Comment: @MikeL. i updated my answear. if you remove the class w-full it will works without gray borders...

Answer (score 0):

I think your img element is too small. Try increasing its size

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I've tried it, didn't help, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I had the same or a very similar issue with v8 of swiper API and images with 100% width (and using srcset):

[image]

Removing the width fixes the issue, but then the images are displayed too small for my case (I use object-fit: cover).

I could solve this by setting the option `loadOnTransitionStart` to `true`: https://v8.swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-lazy-loadOnTransitionStart.
Using the option `loadPrevNext: true` does also work. Also, when using background images, the issue does not occur.

The only drawback is, if an image is directly chosen from the navigation, the gray border appears again.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve this by setting a border on the SwiperSlide larger than the border of my image.

```
<Swiper
    effect={'cards'}
    grabCursor={true}
    modules={[EffectCards]}
    className="w-[276px] h-[585px]"
  >
    <SwiperSlide className="rounded-3xl">
      <Image
        alt={`App Image Advertise 1`}
        src={Advertise1PNG}
        width={276}
        height={585}
      />
    </SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide className="rounded-3xl">
      <Image
        alt={`App Image Advertise 2`}
        src={Advertise2PNG}
        width={276}
        height={585}
      />
    </SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide className="rounded-3xl">
      <Image
        alt={`App Image Advertise 3`}
        src={Advertise3PNG}
        width={276}
        height={585}
      />
    </SwiperSlide>
  </Swiper>
```